# Script stops working when I add columns

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a script that at one point worked great. I added columns, the script stopped working. I finally realized that when I remove these columns it started working again. It appears to only be a problem on the Listing stats tab. However the C2C script does not work when the Listing Stats code is in place- I am guessing since the Listing Stats script is listed first.

(The script is two part. I need to sort two different tabs differently.)

Any thoughts as to why it would stop working with those extra columns added? New to scripts, please talk slowly ;)

DOC HERE (I believe I have set the settings correctly for anyone to see.)
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/175wBQpoGjRkUOIHjI9e056zhQHOwdexPqGNSEaat-cc/edit#gid=499403712

SCRIPT BELOW

```
function onEdit(){
// -- Listing Stats Tab, sorts by Status (3) then Go Live (15) starting at line 8
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("LISTING STATS");
  var lr = ss.getLastRow();
  var lc = ss.getLastColumn();
  var range = ss.getRange(9, 1, lr - 1, lc)
  range.sort([{column: 2},{column: 15}]);

  // -- C2C Tab, sorts by Status (2) then Closing (8) starting at line 13
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("C2C");
  var lr = ss.getLastRow();
  var lc = ss.getLastColumn();
  var range = ss.getRange(14, 1, lr - 1, lc)
  range.sort([{column: 2},{column: 8}]);


}
```

Comment: This is the error that I get when I press play in the script editor. 
"The coordinates of the range are outside the dimensions of the sheet. (line 11, file "Code")Dismiss"

Comment: This is the error that I get when I press play in the script editor. 
"The coordinates of the range are outside the dimensions of the sheet. (line 11, file "Code")Dismiss"
I have done little to debug because I do not know where to even start. When I remove the Listing Stats section, it works on the C2C. When Listing Stats is in place neither works. When I remove 20+ columns from  Listing Stats it works correctly. Thanks for your help.

Comment: the second:   var lr = ss.getLastRow();

Answer (score -1):

I think the error arises because you are trying to execute 2 `getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName()` at the same time. You can't have 2 active sheets at the same time because only one can be active at a time.

Work on one of the sheets first, then activate the second using [setActiveSheet(sheet, restoreSelection)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app).

Comment: I am sorry, I am new to this. What would I replace in my current script? and would I do it in both or just the second?